# MySQL order by in mongodb findOne()

Tags: php, mongodb

In my mongo collection, I have several records with timestamps. I want to use `findOne()` and return the oldest record with a where parameter.

If it's not possible to use `findOne()`, it's alright. I just need to return the oldest record with a where parameter.

How can this be done in MongoDB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to do this.

```
$request =  $collection_requests->find( array( 'status' => 0 ) );
$request->sort( array( 'created' => 1 ) );
$request->limit(1);
$request->next();
$request = $request->current();
```

Comment: writing the same in fluent way: $request = $collection-> find(array('status'=>0))-> sort(array('created'=>1))-> limit(1)-> getNext();

Answer (score 12):

If you need an *oldest* record, use

```
db.collection.find().sort({ created: *1* }).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
db.collection.find().sort({timestamps : -1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: BTW this is correct answer, but more correctly to sort by '_id' field as it contains timestamp itself `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);`

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to use mongo's autogenerated IDs, so its not necessarily guaranteed that _id contains a timestamp. Anyway, even if you are using mongo IDs, you will only get the insert date. An update to the document's timestamps field would not change the _id field and thus would not return the actual latest timestamp if an older document was updated. SOO -- I disagree that it is "more correct" to sort by _id field. ;)

Comment: Sorting with -1 will get you the reversed result, getting the newest value from the collection